# C++ : Return an range based for loop iterator with inheritate objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, iterator

I have a class `Vertex` and I want to **iterate** on its neighbors in particulars ways, like this for example :

```
Vertex my_v;
for(const Vertex& v : my_v.get_neighbors_closer_than(10.0)
    /* Some code on v*/
// And like this
for(const Vertex& v : my_v.get_neighbors_by_trigonometric_order()
    /* Some code on v*/
```

For this, I created **custom containers and iterators** which iterate the way I want. Then, I need to create an **inheritate** class `DlnVertex : public Vertex` which have most of the time the same behiavour about iterating functions. Thus, I would like to write inside my `DlnVertex` class:

```
DlnVertex my_dv;
for(const DlnVertex& dv : my_dv.get_neighbors_closer_than(10.0))
    /* Some code on dv*/
for(const DlnVertex& dv : get_neighbors_by_trigonometric_order())
    /* Some code on dv*/
```

My custom iterator returns a `Vertex&`, and I need in my class `DlnVertex` to use `DlnVertex` properties, and I don't know how to **avoid re-writing** an iterator for my inheritate class because it would have the same behiavour. Is there any **advice**, **patterns**, or **code examples** which can help me ?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191572/iterator-for-custom-container-with-derived-classes) may help.

Comment: thank you, I could write something like this, but I'd like to have a **return type of a DlnVertex iterator** in my inherited class for the functions `get_neighbors_closer_than` and the other.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way : Template my base class for the return types of my functions :

```
template<typename VertexType>
class Vertex
{
    /* ... */
    MyContainer<VertexType> get_neighbors_closer_than(double rad);
}
```

And then design my derived class by setting itself as the template type :

```
class DlnVertex : public Vertex<DlnVertex>{/* ... */}
```